# Sourcing a script from a Git pre-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I'm testing a  git pre-receive hook in a server. This are the contents of the `hooks/pre-receive`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi $USER"
source pre-receive-hooks/bye
```

The contents of `hooks/pre-receive-hooks/bye` are:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bye $USER"
```

Both `hooks/pre-receive` and `hooks/pre-receive-hooks/bye` files are executable, have the same permissions, and same owner and group.

When I push from a client to the server I get the message:

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 287.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Hi sergioro
remote: hooks/pre-receive: line 10: pre-receive-hooks/bye: No such file or directory
To drop:/git/hooks_practice.git
   3fbfa15..c15d08d  master -> master
```

The first `echo` is working but then the `source` command fails. Why is the `source` is failing? Or more generally, how to source a script from within a Git hook?

I also tried the following commands but all return the same error when I push:

```
source ./pre-receive-hooks/bye   # relative path
. pre-receive-hooks/bye          # source using the dot command
./pre-receive-hooks/bye          # run script directly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `source pre-receive-hooks/bye` to `source hooks/pre-receive-hooks/bye` solved the problem. Apparently Git hooks have `$PWD`  equal to the root directory of the repository, not the hooks directory.

Comment: The documentation (`githooks(5)`) outlines the working directory that's used for a hook invocation.